# How trimToSize in Arraylist works?

Tags: java

Javadoc says "

> "Trims the capacity of this ArrayList instance to be the list's current size"

Below is the Test program used to understand the function,

```
ArrayList<Integer> arraylist = new ArrayList<Integer>(50);
    arraylist.add(1);
    arraylist.add(2);
    arraylist.add(3);
    arraylist.add(4);
    arraylist.add(5);
    arraylist.add(6);
    arraylist.add(7);
    arraylist.add(1);
    arraylist.add(1);
    arraylist.add(1);
    System.out.println(arraylist);
    arraylist.trimToSize();
    System.out.println(arraylist);
```

But the output is same in both case.

> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 1, 1]

Can anyone help me understand how this method is used to shrink the arraylist size?

Comment: I saw the link you posted. But that doesn't solve my question. My question is very simple, before and after trimTosize method, the arraylist prints the same data. What advantage does trimToSize method provides?

Comment: Read the answers in the linked question. They exaktly answer that.

Comment: The `ArrayList` is backed by an array, for efficiency, that array can be larger than the number elements contained within the `List`, `trimToSize`, trims the backing buffer so that it's size is the same as the number of elements in the buffer

Comment: it trims the internal array to the needed length? when you remove items the array doesn´t magicly get smaller, it stays the old size, aswell as after adding items the list may get 1.5 times the size it has been before. This results in many unused array elements. The method can just trim the internal array to fit the actual amount of items...

Comment: So In the example I provided,before calling the trimToSize method the arraylist has a array of size 50?

Comment: nope, the internal `size` variable does have the size of 50, not the array in the `ArrayList` itself. These two are used seperate, as the `ArrayList#size` method does use the `size` variable and not the `Storage.length` option.

Comment: The Initial capacity defined for the ArrayList defined in your code is 50. when you call the trimToSize method. It trims the size of arraylist from 50 to 10. This is because your array list holds only 10 elements, so the capacity gets reduced from 50 to 10.

Answer (score 2):

[Use the source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.trimToSize%28%29), Luke!

```
/**
 * Trims the capacity of this <tt>ArrayList</tt> instance to be the
 * list's current size.  An application can use this operation to minimize
 * the storage of an <tt>ArrayList</tt> instance.
 */
public void trimToSize() {
    modCount++;
    if (size < elementData.length) {
        elementData = (size == 0)
          ? EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA
          : Arrays.copyOf(elementData, size);
    }
}
```